# Error in MatLab function isisomorphic

Tags: matlab

I am checking to see if two colored graphs are isomorphic using the built-in MatLab function `isisomorphic`.  The program, however, is throwing me an error.  I would like to know if this is a MatLab error or if there is a mistake in my code.  The specific example where `isisomorphic` fails is reproduced below.  The error is also reproduced below.  The problem is that the code tries to concatenate two objects, `compBinSize(bins1)` and `compBinSize(bins2)`, but one is `4x1` while the other is `1x4`.  Do others get the same error, and if so how do I resolve this?

Note: I am running `Windows 7`, `MatLab R2016b`.

Sample code:

```
G1 = [0 1 1 1 ; 1 0 0 0 ; 1 0 0 0 ; 1 0 0 0]; 

G2 = [0 1 1 0 ; 1 0 1 0; 1 1 0 0 ; 0 0 0 0];

H1 = graph(G1); 

H2 = graph(G2); 

isisomorphic(H1,H2)

Error in graph/isomorphism>refineNodeCategories (line 178) compSizes = [compBinSize(bins1), compBinSize(bins2)];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue.  See the following bug report to resolve it:

https://www.mathworks.com/support/bugreports/1465853